# java web playframework: how to ignore Evaluating Expression in a Template?

Tags: playframework

In view (may be Application/index.html), I had the content like:

```
...
<div>${don't need evaluate this content} </div>
...
```

I don't want Play! evaluate it, only display absolutely this content on screen, so how can I do it ?

#### Update:

Thank Loic and Niels, I have just checked them, both solutions:

```
#{verbatim}${don't need evaluate this content}#{/verbatim}
```

and

```
<div>'${don't need evaluate this content}' </div>
```

didn't work!

Note that, I use XML in response type.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get this working using the following

```
<div>&#36;{don't need evaluate this content}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use the verbatim tag:

```
#{verbatim}${don't need evaluate this content}#{/verbatim}
```

Comment: `verbatim` tag only tells Play not to escape characters that are special in HTML.  Template processing is still performed.

Answer (score 0):

From my groovy experience I would guess to use simple quotes so

```
<div>'${don't need evaluate this content}' </div>
```

But it's not tested. Perhaps `\$` works too. At least `&#36;` instead of $ should work.

Answer (score 0):

All above didn't work in multilines.
Solution:

```
${"""  ANY
THING 
IN HERE"""}
```

`"""`   is here-doc expression in Groovy and PHP.
`'''`   is also here-doc without evaluation.

so, we can also do `%{print(''' ${test} ''')}%`